# WordPress/bbPress separate users

Tags: wordpress, networking, plugins, bbpress

I want to have user to register separately for WordPress or bbPress. I looked for any kind of plugin with no luck, I even created a network in hope the two sites would have separate users, but I tried to register a demo user in second website it just redirected me to the first one.

Anyone has a solution for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to use [HyperDB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/) to be able to use more than one database in a network.